# kronecker product of three matrices

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Facts: For matrices $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $i=1, 2, 3$, we have the following equation:
$$ A_1\otimes A_2 \otimes A_3 = (A_1\otimes I_{n^2})(I_{n}\otimes A_2 \otimes I_n)(I_{n^2}\otimes A_3),
$$
where $I_n$ represents an $n$ by $n$ identity matrix, and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.

My question is what would happen in the equation if matrices $A_i$ are not square matrices, i.e., $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where $m,n$ are not necessarily equal. Is there a way to prove it?

Thank you very much!

Pulong

Comment: Why do you need three *A*s? For your non-square matrices, how do you write your equation for two *A*s? with what "identity" matrices?

Comment: If n>m , for instance, you may embed your m×n matrices as blocks in n×n ones, and apply your formula unchanged.

Comment: @CosmasZachos For instance, if I have three covariance matrix in three different spaces $\mathcal{X}_1, \mathcal{X}_2, \mathcal{X}_3$, I will have three squared matrices. The kronecker product of these three matrices gives the covariance matrix for the product space $\mathcal{X}_1\times \mathcal{X}_2 \times \mathcal{X}_3$. These three matrices do not necessarily have same dimensions, since the number of points in each space can be different.There is a typo in my above question for the notation $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. It should be $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{m_i\times n_i}$

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your comment. I am not sure how I can embed my $m_i\times n_i$ matrices as blocks in a one big matrice. For the identity matrix $I_{n}$, I mean its diagnoal is 1, and other entries are zeros.

Comment: An m×n matrix has m rows and n columns (more than m). Consider the n×n matrix whose upper m rows are those of the m×n, and the rest zero. You are now dealing with square matrices. Appreciate the particular dimension of each in each tensor subspace is completely irrelevant. Now your Identity matrices are square and well-defined. My point is you needlessly confuse yourself by a triple tensor product, instead of a double one.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Agreed. I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Equation for three matrices**

Let $A_i$ be an $(r_i \times c_i)$ matrix for $i = 1,2,3$ and $I_u$ denote the $(u \times u)$ identity matrix. Then,
$$
(A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes A_3) = 
(A_1 \otimes I_{r_2} \otimes I_{r_3})
(I_{c_1} \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3})
(I_{c_1} \otimes I_{c_2} \otimes A_3).
$$

> **Proof**
> This can be proved using two properties of Kronecker products.
>
> *Property 1.*
> Kronecker product is associative, i.e.
> $$
> (A \otimes B) \otimes C = A \otimes (B \otimes C) \tag{1}
> $$
> where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are rectangular matrices.
>
> *Property 2.*
> The product of two Kronecker products yields another Kronecker product:
> $$
> (AB \otimes CD) = (A \otimes B) (C \otimes D)
> $$
> where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are rectangular matrices, and matrix multiplications $AB$ and $CD$ well-defined.
>
> These properties of Kronecker product are well-known and can be found in various resources. I have used [the report by Kathrin Schäcke](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf).
>
> Equation (1) can rewritten using above:
> \begin{align*} 
> A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes A_3 &=  A_1 I_{c_1} \otimes A_2 I_{c_2} \otimes I_{r_3} A_3  \\ 
> &=  (A_1 I_{c_1} \otimes A_2 I_{c_2}) \otimes I_{r_3} A_3  \\
> &=  (A_1 \otimes A_2)(I_{c_1} \otimes I_{c_2}) \otimes I_{r_3} A_3  \\
> &=  (A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3})(I_{c_1} \otimes I_{c_2}\otimes A_3). 
> \tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> The term $(A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3})$ can also be rewritten using the properties above:
> \begin{align*} 
> A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3} &=  A_1 I_{c_1} \otimes I_{r_2} A_2 \otimes I_{r_3} I_{r_3} \\
> &=  A_1 I_{c_1} \otimes (I_{r_2} A_2 \otimes I_{r_3} I_{r_3}) \\
> &=  A_1 I_{c_1} \otimes (I_{r_2} \otimes I_{r_3})(A_2 \otimes I_{r_3}) \\
> &= (A_1 \otimes I_{r_2} \otimes I_{r_3}) (I_{c_1} \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3}). 
> \tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Then, it follows that,
> \begin{align*} 
> A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes A_3 
> &=  (A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3})(I_{c_1} \otimes I_{c_2}\otimes A_3) \\ 
> &=  (A_1 \otimes I_{r_2} \otimes I_{r_3}) (I_{c_1} \otimes A_2 \otimes I_{r_3}) (I_{c_1} \otimes I_{c_2}\otimes A_3) \\
> \end{align*}
> from Equation (2) and Equation (3).

**General Equation**

Equation (1) can be generalized to $n$ matrices. Let $n > 1$ be an integer and $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{r_i \times c_i}$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Davio (1981) proved that
$$
A_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes A_n = \prod_{k = 1}^{n} ( I_{c_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes I_{c_{k-1}} \otimes A_{k} \otimes I_{r_{k+1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes I_{r_{n}} ).
$$
This general formula can also be proven using induction.

It is also worth noting that, the Shuffle algorithm (Plateau, 1985) that is used to multiply a vector with Kronecker product of matrices is based on this formula. The advantage of the Shuffle algorithm is that the Kronecker product of the matrices are not explicitly generated. A discussion on vector-Kronecker product multiplication algorithms can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879933/vector-multiplication-with-multiple-kronecker-products/4379422#4379422).

**References**

Davio, M. (1981). Kronecker products and shuffle algebra. IEEE Transactions on Computers, 100(2), 116-125. doi: [10.1109/TC.1981.6312174](https://doi.org/10.1109/TC.1981.6312174)

Plateau, B. (1985). On the stochastic structure of parallelism and synchronization models for distributed algorithms. SIGMETRICS Performance Evaluation Review, 13(2), 147–154. doi: [10.1145/317786.317819](https://doi.org/10.1145/317786.317819)