# Is there a way to compute $(A\otimes B)x$ quickly without forming the Kronecker product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Is there a way to compute $(A\otimes B)x$ quickly without forming the Kronecker product?  Often, I'd like to compute the matrix-vector product of a Kronecker product, but I'm not sure of a good way to efficiently produce the product directly.  In case it's any easier, I'm also interested in the computing $(A\otimes A)x$.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A basic property of [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) products is
$$(A\otimes B)\,{\rm vec}(X) = {\rm vec}(BXA^T)$$
where the RHS does not contain any Kronecker products, although it does require a vectorization (and de-vectorization) operation.

Similarly 
$$(A\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(X) = {\rm vec}(AXA^T)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a specific case of vector-Kronecker product multiplication with two matrices in the Kronecker product. It is possible to compute
$$
(A_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes A_d) x
$$
without explicitly computing Kronecker product and vectorization. Details of algorithms to compute vector-Kronecker product multiplication can be found in [Vector Multiplication with Multiple Kronecker Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879933/vector-multiplication-with-multiple-kronecker-products/4379422#4379422)