# Complexity of matrix-vector multiplication for Kronecker products

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

Considering the following matrix-vector multiplication:
\begin{align}
(A\otimes B)x
\end{align}
where $A$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $B$ is $m \times m$ matrix. In naive way, it can be computed with complexity $O(n^2m+nm^2)$ rather than the complexity of schoolbook multiplication $O(n^2m^2)$, considering the decomposition
\begin{align}
(A\otimes I_m)(I_n\otimes B)x.
\end{align}
Is there any clever way to reduce the complexity?

(it is a [duplicated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879933/vector-multiplication-with-multiple-kronecker-products) but there is no answer in the link.)

Comment: You get the same result ($n^2m+nm^2$) using $\mathrm{vec}(BXA^T)=(A\otimes B)x$, where $X$ is $m\times n$ reshaped vector $x$. I doubt there is a more efficient way of performing the product (at least in terms of the operations required).

Comment: Thanks for providing better interpretation than mine!